# How to echo color quotes in this batch function?

Tags: batch, findstr

I have the following script with a colored echo function:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H#$E# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do (
  set "DEL=%%a"
)
::call :c 0b "^!<>&| abc123 %%%%"*?"
rem Prepare a file "X" with only one dot
<nul > X set /p ".=."


call :c 0f " [DBName] ["Value=Data"] ["Value=Data"] "
exit


:c
set "param=^%~2" !
set "param=!param:"=\"!"
findstr /p /A:%1 "." "!param!\..\X" nul
<nul set /p ".=%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%%DEL%"
if /i not "%3"=="/n" echo.
exit /b
```

The line `call :c 0f " [DBName] ["Value=Data"] ["Value=Data"] "` does not work. How can I get it to work?

Comment: No idea. But the value of `%3` is breaking `if /i not "%3"=="/n" echo.`

Comment: That line expands to `if /i not "Data"] ["Value"=="/n" echo.` which is where the invalid syntax comes from. Go figure ...

Comment: It works fine for me. It reads as “” when %3 is undefined

Comment: Yes, but `%3` is not undefined. Try adding `echo %3` in your subroutine ...

Comment: If %3 is not defined it has quotes so it works fine. That’s how you test then with    If “%3”==“” echo undefined

Comment: Try adding echo “%3” and it will not return echo is off